# BASH - Syntax error near unexpected token 'done'

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I'm new to programming in bash and am trying to write a script. So far it's very rudimentary but I'm getting the above error with the `done` at the end.

```
for ((i = 1; i < 13; i++)) do
    if [ "$i" -lt "4" ]; then
        touch Block1/B8IT11"$i".txt
        echo B8IT11"$i" created
    else if [ "$i" -gt "3" -a  "$i" -lt "7" ]; then
        touch Block2/B8IT11"$i".txt
        echo B8IT11"$i" created
    else if [ "$i" -lt "6" -a  "$i" -lt "10" ]; then
        touch Block3/B8IT11"$i".txt
        echo B8IT11"$i" created
    else
        touch Block4/B8IT11"$i".txt
        echo B8IT11"$i" created
    fi
done
```

To my eyes I can't see the issue, as the `if-else if-else` ends with `fi` and the `for` loop should terminate with the `done`.

I've done `cat -v` and even `dos2unix` it. Does anyone see something I'm missing?

Comment: Try shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `else if` in bash. What you have is an `else` followed by a (nested) `if` construct. The outer `else` is unterminated (missing `fi`). Bash thinks you're still in an `else` block so it's not expecting `done` at this point:

```
for ((i = 1; i < 13; i++)) do
    if [ "$i" -lt "4" ]; then
        touch Block1/B8IT11"$i".txt
        echo B8IT11"$i" created
    else
        if [ "$i" -gt "3" -a  "$i" -lt "7" ]; then
            touch Block2/B8IT11"$i".txt
            echo B8IT11"$i" created
        else
            if [ "$i" -lt "6" -a  "$i" -lt "10" ]; then
                touch Block3/B8IT11"$i".txt
                echo B8IT11"$i" created
            else
                touch Block4/B8IT11"$i".txt
                echo B8IT11"$i" created
            fi
            done
```

---

Fix: Change all your `else if` to `elif`.

Comment: Ah thanks, am coming from more of a c# background so completely missed that. Cheers!

Comment: There's also a missing semicolon before `do`.

Answer (score 1):

In bash `else if` is used as `elif`. you can try this:-

```
for ((i = 1; i < 13; i++)) do
    if [ "$i" -lt "4" ]; then
        touch Block1/B8IT11"$i".txt
        echo B8IT11"$i" created
    elif [ "$i" -gt "3" -a  "$i" -lt "7" ]; then
        touch Block2/B8IT11"$i".txt
        echo B8IT11"$i" created
    elif [ "$i" -lt "6" -a  "$i" -lt "10" ]; then
        touch Block3/B8IT11"$i".txt
        echo B8IT11"$i" created
    else
        touch Block4/B8IT11"$i".txt
        echo B8IT11"$i" created
    fi
done
```